firebase not creating new user after flutter upgrade
E/flutter (22614):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/flutter (22614):  ... 3 more
E/flutter (22614): Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
E/flutter (22614):  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:5)
E/flutter (22614):  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:9)
E/flutter (22614):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebasePluginRegistry.lambda$getPluginConstantsForFirebaseApp$0(FlutterFirebasePluginRegistry.java:55)
E/flutter (22614):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebasePluginRegistry$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter (22614):  ... 3 more
E/flutter (22614): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
E/flutter (22614):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.lambda$getPluginConstantsForFirebaseApp$16(FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java:689)

my flutter app can no longer create a new user in firebase but it was working before

It's gonna be hard to say what's going on here without seeing minimal repro.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
